# Typescript: Infer exact values from dynamically created object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to infer the exact values from an object thats dynamically created with a helper function.

The values of the object will always be inferred as type string, but I would like to have their exact value, like my attempt at casting on the SIGN_IN declaration.

```
const createAsyncActionTypes = (label: string) => ({
  REQUEST: `${label}_${'SUCCESS'}`,
  SUCCESS: `${label}_${'SUCCESS'}`,
  ERROR: `${label}_${'ERROR'}`,
  CANCELLED: `${label}_${'CANCELLED'}`,
});

const SIGN_OUT = createAsyncActionTypes('SIGN_OUT');

const SIGN_IN: {
  REQUEST: 'SIGN_IN_REQUEST';
  SUCCESS: 'SIGN_IN_SUCCESS';
  ERROR: 'SIGN_IN_ERROR';
  CANCELLED: 'SIGN_IN_CANCELLED';
} = createAsyncActionTypes('SIGN_IN');
```

Comment: Not possible currently for the compiler to infer the types of string operations unfortunately

Comment: ... and why would you need that? There is probably a way without building up string keys.

Comment: Feels like [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13969), maybe go there to give it a  and/or describe your use case if you think it's more compelling than the ones listed there

Comment: Yes I agree @JonasWilms, but this is more for a migration to typescript from plain js issue, we have hundreds of 'asyncActionTypes' as a way to reduce having to write out each request, success, error and cancelled. I will look at a different async action types. And will refer to the issue listed above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible.

You could cast the individual values to their related types, but that would defeat the point of dynamically creating the object:

[image]

Typescript does not support "dynamic typing" like that.